# Shiny: How to make the title of navbarPage() fill the window?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, shiny-server

I want to make the Area 1 fill the window, and the Area 2 has a fixed width.
[image]

The final results should be like:
[image]

My code is shown as following:

```html
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
ui <- fixedPage(
  tags$style(HTML("
          .navbar .navbar-header {float: left; }
          .navbar .navbar-nav {float: right;}
          .container {min-width: 1250px}
        ")
  ),
  navbarPage(
    windowTitle = "GMAP",
    fluid = TRUE,
    title = "Title",
    selected = "Density",
    tabPanel(
      "Introduction",
    ),
    tabPanel(
      "Combination"
    ),
    tabPanel(
      "Density",
      tabsetPanel(
        selected = "Cluster analysis",
        tabPanel(
          "AAAAAAAAA"
        ),
        tabPanel(
          "BBBBBBBB",
          
        ),
      )
    ),
    tabPanel(
      "Effective score",
    ),
    tabPanel(
      "Effective percent"
    ),
    tabPanel(
      "Help"
    ),      
    tabPanel(
      "About"
    )
  )
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I tried to put a navbarPage() into a fixedPage(), but it can not work correctly. Could you tell me how to achieve my goal?

edit version 2:
Thanks for your answer! I want to make one of the tabpanel() left and make others right, like below:
[image]

I tried to set padding by the code:

```html
.nav-tabs>li:nth-child(1) {margin-right: 305px; }
```

However, all first tabpanel will be changed if I do this, like below:
[image]

I think this problem can be solved by set a unique id for the tabpanel I want to make it left align, but I can not achieve the goal by add id = "density_ui_definition". I know it is correct in div(id = "XXX"), but tabpanel(id = "XXX") does not work. I have make the releated chagnes in your code

```html
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
ui <-   div(
  tags$style(HTML("
        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            body > div .container-fluid {
                width: 750px;
            }
        }
        @media (min-width: 992px) {
            body > div > .container-fluid {
                width: 970px;
            }
        }
        @media (min-width: 1200px) {
            body > div .container-fluid {
                width: 1170px;
            }
        }
        body > div > .container-fluid:nth-of-type(1) {
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding-top: 55px;
        }
        body > div > nav .nav.navbar-nav {
            float: right;
        }
        
        .nav-tabs>li { float: left; margin-bottom: -1px; padding-right: 200px}
        
        ")),
  navbarPage(
    position = "fixed-top",
    windowTitle = "GMAP",
    fluid = TRUE,
    title = div(id = "img-main",
                img(src="logo.png", height = '32px', width = '133px'),
                style = ""),
    selected = "Density",
    tabPanel(
      "Introduction",
    ),
    tabPanel(
      "Combination"
    ),
    tabPanel(
      "Density",
      tabsetPanel(
        selected = "BBBBBBBB",
        tabPanel(
          "AAAAAAAAA",
          tags$img(src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtaJC.png", style = "width: 100%")
        ),
        tabPanel(
          "BBBBBBBB",
          tabsetPanel(
            selected = "CCC",
            tabPanel(
              "CCC"
            ),
            tabPanel(
              "DDD"
            ),
          )
        )
      )
    ),
    tabPanel(
      "Effective score",
    ),
    tabPanel(
      "Effective percent"
    ),
    tabPanel(
      "Help"
    ),      
    tabPanel(
      "About"
    ),
    hr(),
    tags$footer(
      HTML("<p>Copyright © 2022 All Rights Reserved.</p>"), 
      align = "right"
    )
  )
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Can you help me modify it agin? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
ui <- div(
    tags$style(HTML("
        @media (min-width: 1200px) {
            body > div > .container-fluid {
                width: 1170px;
            }
        }
        @media (min-width: 992px) {
            body > div > .container-fluid {
                width: 970px;
            }
        }
        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            body > div > .container-fluid {
                width: 750px;
            }
        }
        ")),
    navbarPage(
        windowTitle = "GMAP",
        fluid = TRUE,
        title = "Title",
        selected = "Density",
        tabPanel(
            "Introduction"
        ),
        tabPanel(
            "Combination"
        ),
        tabPanel(
            "Density",
            tabsetPanel(
                selected = "Cluster analysis",
                tabPanel(
                    "AAAAAAAAA"
                ),
                tabPanel(
                    "BBBBBBBB"
                )
            )
        ),
        tabPanel(
            "Effective score"
        ),
        tabPanel(
            "Effective percent"
        ),
        tabPanel(
            "Help"
        ),      
        tabPanel(
            "About"
        )
    )
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Change `width` inside `media` to numbers you want.

[image]

#### Edits:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
ui <- div(
  tags$style(HTML("
        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            body > div .container-fluid {
                width: 750px;
            }
        }
        @media (min-width: 992px) {
            body > div > .container-fluid {
                width: 970px;
            }
        }
        @media (min-width: 1200px) {
            body > div .container-fluid {
                width: 1170px;
            }
        }
        body > div > .container-fluid:nth-of-type(1) {
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding-top: 55px;
        }
        body > div > nav .nav.navbar-nav {
            float: right;
        }
        ")),
  navbarPage(
    position = "fixed-top",
    windowTitle = "GMAP",
    fluid = TRUE,
    title = "Title",
    selected = "Density",
    tabPanel(
      "Introduction"
    ),
    tabPanel(
      "Combination"
    ),
    tabPanel(
      "Density",
      tabsetPanel(
        selected = "AAAAAAAAA",
        tabPanel(
          "AAAAAAAAA",
          tags$img(src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtaJC.png", style = "width: 100%")
        ),
        tabPanel(
          "BBBBBBBB"
        )
      )
    ),
    tabPanel(
      "Effective score"
    ),
    tabPanel(
      "Effective percent"
    ),
    tabPanel(
      "Help"
    ),      
    tabPanel(
      "About"
    )
  )
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have noticed that the fixedPage was replaced with fluid container. However, fluid container may not be able to make the content in the middle area like the new picture added in the question. I want to make a website like ( http://gepia.cancer-pku.cn/detail.php ). The content was placed in the middle area and the margin fill the window automatically. Can you help me agin? Thank you!

Comment: I added a few rules, see edits. Images are perfectly centered inside.

Comment: Thanks for your help! There are still two problems I do not know how to solve, one of them has been added in the newest post labed by "edit version 2". Another problem is, I used fixedPage to make sure the content will not be folded automatically when the window becomes narrow. I do not know how to achieve this goal when fixedPage was replaced with div().

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have fixed the second problem by add .nav-tabs > li > a[data-value='Definition']{margin-right: 305px; }